# Trying to use .split with two different page URL structures

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

**My intention**
pull out language code from my two type of URL strings

**My question**
How do I make a split between two different URL structures? I have two URL strucutres, listed as examples below under the code.

**My problem**
I can't figure out how I should split the two different variables separately or together in one line with cc =... using custom javascript with Google Tag Manager

Code

```
function() {
    cc = {{Page Path}}.split("/")[1].toLowerCase();
    cc = {{virtualURL}}.split("/#/")[1].toLowerCase();
    if(cc.length == 2) {
        cc = cc;
    } else {
        cc = 'other';
    }
    return cc;
}
```

Example of `{{Page Path}}` - https://www.example.com/en/.....
Example of `{{virtualURL}}` - https://www.booking.example.com/#/en/........

**Note**
In both examples I want to be able to pull out **en** successfully.

Comment: What is your expected result??

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name, so that's a place to start: `cc1` and `cc2`... You also want to declare your variable(s), less you fall prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: As listed at the bottom, the language code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i will test to seperate them

Comment: Appreciate everyone's response, and thx for beeing patient. Pratyush Sharma solution works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take out the language code simply by splitting the URL by `/`. Let's see what we get when we split the two URL's given as the example:

1. https://www.example.com/en/ - ["https:", "", "www.example.com", "en", ""]
2. https://www.booking.example.com/#/en/ - ["https:", "", "www.booking.example.com", "#", "en", ""]

In the above examples we can see that language code is either coming at 3rd index (1st example) or at the 4th index (2nd example) which can be taken care by an `if` condition. Let's see how:

```
let url = 'https://www.booking.example.com/#/en/';
let urlTokens = url.split('/');
let languageCode = urlTokens[3] === '#' ? urlTokens[4] : urlTokens[3];

console.log(languageCode);
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. but the url needs to come from window.location.href, and i can't use "let" declaration.

Comment: I have used 'let' for demonstration purpose only. You can write 'let url = window.location.href' to get the page URL.
You can use plain old 'var' instead of 'let' also.

Comment: Ok, so i tried this code - function(){
var url = window.location.href;
var urlTokens = url.split('/');
var languageCode = url[3] === '#' ? url[4] : url[3];

return languageCode;
}

But it only returns either 'p' or 'd', not sure why that is?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Use urlTokens instead of URL

Answer (score 2):

Any solution here is likely to be fragile, you could have `https://example.com/xy/` where `xy` isn't meant to be a language code.

But allowing for that, and allowing only two-character language codes:

```js
var rexGetLang = /\/([a-z]{2})\//;

function getLang(url) {
  var match = rexGetLang.exec(url);
  return match ? match[1] : "other";
}

console.log(getLang("https://www.example.com/en/....."));
console.log(getLang("https://www.booking.example.com/#/en/........"));
```

Or if you want to allow for `en-GB` and such:

```js
var rexGetLang = /\/([a-z]{2}(?:-[A-Z]{2})?)\//;

function getLang(url) {
  var match = rexGetLang.exec(url);
  return match ? match[1] : "other";
}

console.log(getLang("https://www.example.com/en/....."));
console.log(getLang("https://www.booking.example.com/#/en/........"));
console.log(getLang("https://www.booking.example.com/........"));

console.log(getLang("https://www.example.com/en-GB/....."));
console.log(getLang("https://www.booking.example.com/#/en-US/........"));
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your input, deeply appreciated. however the structure will always be the same either /en or /#/en. Where the end result is to pull out en, else it should give me "other" so i can troubleshoot.

Comment: unfortunately i can't use console.log, i could however use window.location and window.location.hash - do you think that's possible to use? Not sure where to start if that's correct to be honest

Comment: @Steven - The `console.log` above is just to show you the result. The key thing is the result from `getLang`.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. Is the intention that i should switch out getLang(url) with something? And thanks for the clarification of the console.log, of course, i should've known...

Comment: @Steven - Looking at your original function, I think you'd want `var cc = getLang({{Page Path}}); if (cc === "other") { cc = getLang({{virtualURL}}); }`

Comment: almost, @T.J. Crowder i want to extract the language code from those variables. As explained in my question Page Path provides 1 url structure and virtualURL has another unique url structure. I only want to extract the language code not the whole url, if that makes more sense and clarifies. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Web API for handling URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL
const url = new URL('https://www.example.com/en/website');

url.hostname;  //  'example.com'
url.port;      //  ''
url.search;    //  ''
url.pathname;  //  '/en/website'
url.protocol;  //  'https:'


// RegEx to see if /en/ exists https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
new RegExp(/\/en\//).test(url.pathname) // true
```

Comment: @Steven It's supported by all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLanguage(url) {
    var rgx = /^https:\/\/[^\/]+\/(?:#\/)?([a-z]+)/;    
    var language = url.match(rgx)[1];
    return language;
}

var url = 'https://www.booking.example.com/#/en/';
var language = getLanguage(url);
```

Comment: Thx Willy, i need a return. Would if it be logical if the return is written like this? return language();

Comment: "let" declaration doesn't seem to be supported in Google Tag Manager, doesn't support ECMASCRIPT6.

Comment: would you mind to edit the function to get the URL from window.location.href ? Also the structure for Google Tag Manager needs to be within 1 function. Hope that clarifies, sorry for the confusion on this..